# jQuery files not connecting in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript

The path to my files is wwwroot/js/{filename}

These are the links I am using to connect them.

None of these are connecting. Any solutions?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the '~'. None of those resources have server side runat="server" tags. The tilde char denotes the starting directory for server side operations. Since these are client side resources it is likely the culprit.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
```